# "multiple definition of" linking error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, nasm

I am currently having problems during the linking of my project, which currently manifests themselves under the form of a "multiple definitions of" error, for every single one of my functions.

I have no idea why such an error is occurring since I did not change the build system recently. I did try to clean the project (that is, deleting the obj and bin folders), but that did nothing to alleviate the problem.

Note that most of my code is made in assembly (The assembler I use is NASM btw), which means that there should be no problem such as having headers included multiple times (there are no headers in my project (should probably have some for the assembly function definitions)).

I uploaded the current console output to Pastebin, [here](https://pastebin.com/qiQLXRAU).
Note that the console commands are generated by my IDE, `Code::Blocks`.

Also, even though most of the errors concern my ASM version of the street, that is probably simply because it is the last function in alphabetical order, so it is the first to be linked (and because there is 50 errors max (I think)).

Also, I don't know why links to Pastebin must be accompanied by code, but I guess here is the start of my street function if you think it's because of it that I have build problems :

```
global @ASM_strset@8

segment .text align=16

%define string ecx  ; char *, string to modify
%define character edx      ; char, value to fill string with
%define result eax   ; char *, string, now filled with character
%define backCharacter esi
%define loBackCharacter si
%define backString ebx
%define scasbAddr edi
%define scasbChar eax
%define scasbLimit ecx
%define stosbChar ax
%define stosbAddr edi

@ASM_strset@8:
    mov backCharacter, character
    mov backString, string
```

EDIT: Someone indicated that the commands outputted by `C::B` are broken, but I don't really see how `C::B` could generate such broken commands from a project file (that looks rather normal) like [this](https://pastebin.com/pajC4umz).

EDIT 2 : Here are the macros that C::B generates the commands from :

```
.cpp files : $compiler $options $includes -c $file -o $object
.asm files : nasm -f elf32 $file -o $object
```

Note that I added the macro for assembly files myself, and that they worked for the past few months

Comment: Your console commands are all totally wrong and broken, but no one can tell you how to fix them because no one has the source project they are generated from.

Comment: Well the project file looked rather normal, I'm gonna post it to pastebin and link to it in an edit

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved itself : After the twentieth time I closed and re-opened, the project, it just worked for no reason whatsoever (I tried closing and re-opening multiple times, as well as closing CodeBlocks entirely and even re-booting my computer, but until now it didn't work)

EDIT : The console output now looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/qUNPULHV), which probably looks normal. The object file names that are given to NASM now look like those given to g++, like this :

```
nasm -f elf32 "C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Documents\ecole\Franc_sais\3e\Chapitre_1\SNES_ROMs\Programming\Projects\Assembly\Generic Samples\atoi.asm" -o obj\Release\atoi.o
```

Comment: Also idk why I can't accept my answer in less than two days, so I'm posting this to avoid people downvoting me for not marking my question as solved

Comment: Could you please report a but to Code::Blocks team.

Comment: Problem being that I never get the email I'm supposed to receive so I can register (yes I did check my spam and my trash folder and I also made a manual search)